# How to move the skills, hobbies and languages details in the “Designer's CV” template

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, templates, cv

I'm using this [CV template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/designer%27s-cv) found on ShareLaTeX/Overleaf site (source: http://www.howtotex.com/):

```
%%% LaTeX Template: Designer's CV
%%%
%%% Source: http://www.howtotex.com/
%%% Feel free to distribute this template, but please keep the referal to HowToTeX.com.
%%% Date: March 2012


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@howtotex.com}  \\
    \url{www.howtotex.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} John Doe} \\
\Large\bfseries  Graphics designer \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

% Experience
\CVSection{Experience}
\CVItem{May 2010 - present, Lorem ipsum}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Aug 2007 - Feb 2010, Vivamus vel}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus.
\Sep

% Education
\CVSection{Education}
\CVItem{2010 - present, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2007 - 2010, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2005 - 2007, Vivamus vel bibendum}\\
Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\Sep

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep 

\CVSection{Something other}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.

\clearpage
\framebreak
\framebreak

\CVSection{Something else}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

How can I move skills, languages and hobbies section to the left frame, below the contact information?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code, please without personal informations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the code for the left frame like this (see the important code changings marked with `<======`):

```
% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
%   \vspace{-7cm} % <===================================================
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@howtotex.com}  \\
    \url{www.howtotex.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\SmallSep % <===========================================================
\begin{flushright}\small % <============================================
    {\Large Skills} \\
  {\large Platforms}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{flushright}\normalsize % <=========================================
\SmallSep
\begin{flushleft}\small % <============================================
    {\Large Skills} \\
  {\large Platforms}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
{\large Computer software}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{flushleft}\normalsize % <==========================================
\SmallSep
\vfill % <==============================================================
\framebreak
```

Please see that I showed one example with environment `flushright` and one with `flushleft`. Choose that you like more (I would prefer the first one). Please see you need to rework the distances between the new titles (**not** set with `\CVSection` or `\CVItem`. I left that for you and for your taste ...

So the complete code

```
%%% LaTeX Template: Designer's CV
%%%
%%% Source: http://www.howtotex.com/
%%% Feel free to distribute this template, but please keep the referal to HowToTeX.com.
%%% Date: March 2012


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
    (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{photo}
%   \vspace{-7cm} % <===================================================
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@howtotex.com}  \\
    \url{www.howtotex.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\SmallSep % <===========================================================
\begin{flushright}\small % <============================================
    {\Large Skills} \\
  {\large Platforms}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{flushright}\normalsize % <=========================================
\SmallSep
\begin{flushleft}\small % <============================================
    {\Large Skills} \\
  {\large Platforms}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
{\large Computer software}\\
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{flushleft}\normalsize % <==========================================
\SmallSep
\vfill % <==============================================================
\framebreak


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} John Doe} \\
\Large\bfseries  Graphics designer \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

% Experience
\CVSection{Experience}
\CVItem{May 2010 - present, Lorem ipsum}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Aug 2007 - Feb 2010, Vivamus vel}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus.
\Sep

% Education
\CVSection{Education}
\CVItem{2010 - present, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2007 - 2010, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2005 - 2007, Vivamus vel bibendum}\\
Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\Sep

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep 

\CVSection{Something other}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.

\clearpage
\framebreak
\framebreak

\CVSection{Something else}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\Sep

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

results in this pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]